# Possible max matchings

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

our children (J/K/L/M) each wants a piece of fruit. There are five pieces of fruit available: an apple, a banana, a nectarine, an orange and a pear.

J likes bananas and nectarines.

K likes apples, nectarines, oranges and pears.

L likes apples and bananas.

M likes oranges and pears.

How many possible maximal matching are there?

**Options: 4/5/3/2**

Found something similar posted but still a bit confused:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26250446/maximum-matching-for-assigning-2-items
```

Comment: Are you looking for a general method? or just having trouble finding the matchings in this case?

Comment: For this case. Found general explanation in link I have mentioned but not able to get answer for this.

Comment: For clarification then, you wish to count what exactly?  The number of ways of distributing *all five* fruit to the children such that every child gets at least one fruit?  (my previous answer assumed we were counting number of ways of distributing fruit to the children such that each child got exactly one piece of fruit, leaving a piece unused)

Comment: Yes but along with considering their choice. So distributing by choice (Pref J, K,L,M order) if a fruit is given to J that is out of option for K and K get second priority fruit.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we assign a number to the fruit  based on alphabetical order. (this is just to save space and time, it's not really needed to solve it).

Apple = 1 ; Banana = 2 ; Nectarine = 3 ; Orange = 4 ; Pear = 5

In the end it's about writing four digits numbers assuming that J is the thousand, K the hundred, L the tens and M the units.

Thousands can be only 2 or 3.
Hundreds can be 1,3,4 or 5.
Tens can be only 1 or 2.
Units can be only 4 or 5.
Digits cannot be repeated.

(Example: 2314 means J gets banana, K gets Nectarine, L gets apple and M gets orange)

2314, 2315, 2415, 2514, 3124, 3125, 3415, 3425, 3514, 3524.

That's it. There's a total of 10 maximal matching.

**EDIT**

Here is an algorithm with Maple to find out the number of matching and the matching themselves.

`N := 0:
for J from 2 to 3 do
    for K from 1 to 5 do
        if not(K=J) and not(K=2) then
        for L from 1 to 2 do
           if not(L=J) and not(L=K) then
           for M from 4 to 5 do
               if not(M=K) then
                   N := N + 1;
               end if;
           end do;
           end if;
        end do;
        end if;
    end do;
end do;
'total' = N;
V := Vector(N):
X := 0:
for J from 2 to 3 do
    for K from 1 to 5 do
        if not(K=J) and not(K=2) then
        for L from 1 to 2 do
           if not(L=J) and not(L=K) then
           for M from 4 to 5 do
               if not(M=K) then
                   X := X + 1;
                   V[X] := J * 1000 + K * 100 + L* 10 + M;
               end if;
           end do;
           end if;
        end do;
        end if;
    end do;
end do;
'matching' = V;`